# Correct way to write a params api in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-api-nodejs-client, nodejs-server

`app.post('/scripts/:freezeId', scriptsView.findAll);`

`app.post('/scripts/deleteScripts', scriptsView.deleteconfig);`

Is the only way the second API needs to write on top of the params API or any other ideas are available in node js

Answer (score 0):

Express tries to match routes in order.

So, typically, the URL `/scripts/deleteScripts` will match `'/scripts/:freezeId'` and run `scriptsView.findAll`. Then `scriptsView.findAll` will send a response and end the handling of that request.

Now, `scriptsView.findAll` *could* special case `deleteScripts` and call `next()` instead, but that means `scriptsView.findAll` has to know about things outside its remit.

Changing the order so `'/scripts/deleteScripts',` is tested first is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `app.post` you can use `app.delete` for delete scripts API